# How can I edit multipart/form-data request data in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: java, spring-cloud, multipartform-data, spring-webflux, gateway

I'm using spring cloud gateway to do parameter check, how can I edit multipart/form-data request data?

I can read the parameters, but I don't know how to edit it.

I think the key of the problem is that I don't know how to serialize and deserialize the request parameters.

```
if (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.isCompatibleWith(mediaType)) {
            exchange.getRequest().getBody().collectList().flatMap(dataBuffers -> {
                final byte[] totalBytes = dataBuffers.stream().map(dataBuffer -> {
                    try {
                        final byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(dataBuffer.asInputStream());
                        return bytes;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).reduce(this::addBytes).get();
                final ServerHttpRequestDecorator decorator = new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest()) {
                    @Override
                    public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
                        return Flux.just(buffer(totalBytes));
                    }
                };
                final ServerCodecConfigurer configurer = ServerCodecConfigurer.create();
                final Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> multiValueMapMono = repackageMultipartData(decorator, configurer);

                return multiValueMapMono.flatMap(part -> {
                    for (String key : part.keySet()) {
                       // read parameters

                    }
                    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(decorator).build());
                });

            });

        }


     private DataBuffer buffer(byte[] bytes) {
        final NettyDataBufferFactory nettyDataBufferFactory = new NettyDataBufferFactory(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
        final DataBuffer buffer = nettyDataBufferFactory.allocateBuffer(bytes.length);
        buffer.write(bytes);
        return buffer;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> repackageMultipartData(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        try {
            final MediaType contentType = request.getHeaders().getContentType();
            if (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.isCompatibleWith(contentType)) {
                return ((HttpMessageReader<MultiValueMap<String, Part>>) configurer
                        .getReaders()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(reader -> reader.canRead(MULTIPART_DATA_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No multipart HttpMessageReader.")))
                        .readMono(MULTIPART_DATA_TYPE, request, Collections.emptyMap())
                        .switchIfEmpty(EMPTY_MULTIPART_DATA)
                        .cache();
            }
        } catch (InvalidMediaTypeException ex) {
            // Ignore
        }
        return EMPTY_MULTIPART_DATA;
    }

    public byte[] addBytes(byte[] first, byte[] second) {
        final byte[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }
```

or

Comment: just a question, isn't it just simpler to use the method `Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> multivalueMap = exchange.getMultipartData()` to extract the parts?

Comment: Thank you for your comment，I will try this way.

Comment: How can I edit MultipartData of the exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Well for multi-part request modification especially ones having form data, the process is bit tricky. Unfortunately `ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory` will not help directly because there is no way to convert a string->multi-part->string.

The process is here to read the entire request, convert it into multi part, modify it and then set it back as string to the modified request. Right now there are no factory methods to do this conversion, however you can still use the approach and do some thing like this:

```
             ServerRequest serverRequest = ServerRequest.create(exchange, messageReaders);
            
            // get modified body from original body o
            Mono<MultiValueMap<String, String>> modifiedBody = serverRequest.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(o -> {
                // create mock request to read body
                SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader synchronossReader = new SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader();
                MultipartHttpMessageReader reader = new MultipartHttpMessageReader(synchronossReader);
                MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest.post("").contentType(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getContentType()).body(o);
                Mono<MultiValueMap<String, Part>> monoRequestParts = reader.readMono(MULTIPART_DATA_TYPE, request, Collections.emptyMap());
                // modify parts
                return monoRequestParts.flatMap(requestParts -> {
                    Map<String, List<String>> modifedBodyArray = requestParts.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
                        String key = entry.getKey();
                        LOGGER.info(key);
                        List<String> entries = entry.getValue().stream().map(part -> {
                            LOGGER.info("{}", part);
                            // read the input part
                            String input = ((FormFieldPart) part).value();
                            // return the modified input part
                            return new String(modifyRequest(config, exchange, key, input));
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return new Map.Entry<String, List<String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public String getKey() {
                                return key;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public List<String> getValue() {
                                return entries;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public List<String> setValue(List<String> param1) {
                                return param1;
                            }
                        };
                    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getKey(), k -> k.getValue()));
                    return Mono.just(new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(modifedBodyArray));
                });
            });
            
            // insert the new modified body
            BodyInserter bodyInserter = BodyInserters.fromPublisher(modifiedBody, new ParameterizedTypeReference<MultiValueMap<String, String>>() {});
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.putAll(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders());

            // the new content type will be computed by bodyInserter
            // and then set in the request decorator
            headers.remove(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH);
            
            CachedBodyOutputMessage outputMessage = new CachedBodyOutputMessage(exchange, headers);
            return bodyInserter.insert(outputMessage, new BodyInserterContext())
                    .then(Mono.defer(() -> {
                        ServerHttpRequest decorator = decorate(exchange, headers, outputMessage);
                        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(decorator).build());
                    }));
```